# Media query doesn't work when i resize screen less than 600px

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I have made a table under a division and used the media query to react it as responsive when screen size goes less than 600px. But when I resize my windows less than 600px all the content under table data is come out of the division.
Here is the screenshot of my problem:

[image: https://postimg.org/image/tfv0fd77j/]

And here is my code that I have used to make this table:

```
<div class="myfirst">
        <h1 class="myheading">About Us</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span>HOSTING</span><br>We have top class servers<br>to serve you what you need.</td>
                <td><span>HOSTING</span><br>We have top class servers<br>to serve you what you need.</td>
                <td><span>HOSTING</span><br>We have top class servers<br>to serve you what you need.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<style>
.myfirst {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.myheading {
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
    color: black;
    padding: 25px 196px;
    font-weight: 30;
    margin-left: 75px;
}

tr {
    width: 318px;
    height: 29px;
}

td {
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    padding: 0 32px;
}

td:last-child {
    border: none;
}

@media screen and(max-width:600px) {
    .myfirst {
        width: 100%!important;
        height: 200%;
        background-color: aqua;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    table,td,tr,span {
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0;
    }


</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `@media screen and (max-width:600px)` Add a **space** between `and` and `(max-width:600px)`

```css
.myfirst {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.myheading {
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
    color: black;
    padding: 25px 196px;
    font-weight: 30;
    margin-left: 75px;
}

tr {
    width: 318px;
    height: 29px;
}

td {
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    padding: 0 32px;
}

td:last-child {
    border: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   
    table,td,tr,span {
        margin-left: 0px!important;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .myfirst {
        width: 100%!important;
        height: 200%;
        background-color: aqua;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    table,td,tr,span {
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-left: 0px!important;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="myfirst">
        <h1 class="myheading">About Us</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span>HOSTING</span><br>We have top class servers<br>to serve you what you need.</td>
                <td><span>HOSTING</span><br>We have top class servers<br>to serve you what you need.</td>
                <td><span>HOSTING</span><br>We have top class servers<br>to serve you what you need.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: It still not fixed totally. Thanks for the help. You have the division responsive but still, the content is going out of the division. See here...https://postimg.org/image/51wq7jun3/

Comment: Thanks for accept . I suggest using famous interfacing pages like Bootstrap